# How to do modifications to a view of SQL Server from graphic interface

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I want modify a view in SQL but it show message error when I do click right for open the designer of the view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyjRE.png)

After open my view and I do the changes but when I save it show me a message error, Is this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH72w.png)

Can someone help me?

I look for the message in google and found this. I need deselect `**Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation**`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yqpt.png)

I want know if exist other method or solution to do or this is unique method

Comment: I suggest you avoid using the SSMS designer and use a query window instead.

Comment: The designer for views is a buggy mess that uses deprecated syntax. Steer well clear of it, and ideally forget it exists.

Comment: The view designer can only cope with fairly basic syntax - if you use things like window functions it doesn't know how to cope with that. Don't use it anyway though. It can make unwanted changes to your code even if can parse it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the views in designer. Follow the instructions below to open the existing view.

[image: Instruction to open the view in new query window.]